# Fetching data from mysql to html bootstrap with PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to retrieve data from Database to Html bootstrap table here is my code for php and html both:

```
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h5>Data Tables example</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content">

                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
                    <thead>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","pooling","password");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}   
mysql_select_db("bayansh_bmc", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pooling");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
                    <tr>
                        <th>Province</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Province'] . "</td>";
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
mysql_close($con);

?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

it gives me error at line 78 which is echo "";

Comment: `{
                    <tr>` pure HTML in PHP.

Comment: What the flippin ek is that

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: And while we're on the subject of `<tr>`, you should have a `<tr>...</tr>` inside the `<tbody>`.  For that matter, the while loop probably belongs inside the `<tbody>`.

Comment: I officially hate the new school/college year

Comment: @fred-ii- Then how to get value from php to <tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic tip: HTML is not PHP code:

```
php mode:            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
php mode:            {
html-in-php-mode:        <tr>
```

You can't mix php and html like that. You **HAVE** to use `<?php ... ?>` to tell the parser where your PHP code starts/ends:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  ?>
    ^---note this
    <tr
```

Comment: can you edit my code????

Comment: No. Stop being lazy and type the two characters you're missing yourself.

Comment: i didnt understand that is why i asked O:-)